# Find first match of condition by given variable

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, vectorization

I have data

```
library(data.table); set.seed(42)
dat <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5), x=rnorm(15))
> dat
#    id           x
# 1:  1  1.37095845
# 2:  1 -0.56469817
# 3:  1  0.36312841
# 4:  2  0.63286260
# 5:  2  0.40426832
# 6:  3 -0.10612452
# 7:  3  1.51152200
# 8:  3 -0.09465904
# 9:  3  2.01842371
#10:  3 -0.06271410
#11:  4  1.30486965
#12:  5  2.28664539
#13:  5 -1.38886070
#14:  5 -0.27878877
#15:  5 -0.13332134
```

and I would like to obtain for each `id` the indicies of the first value that meets some condition in `x`. For example, for conditions `x>0`, this would give

```
> res
#[1]  1  4  7 11 12
```

I would hope that `data.table` can be used, as this has always astonished me for its efficiency, but some other function that can do this quickly would work, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the condition in `i`, grouped by 'id', get the indices of the first element with `.I`, extract the column (`$V1`)

```
dat[x >0, .I[1], id]$V1
#[1]  1  4  7 11 12
```

Comment: In case there are some ids that never meet the condition and we want NA for them: `dat[.(id = unique(id), x_dn = 0), on=.(id, x > x_dn), mult="first", which=TRUE]`

Answer (score 2):

This was surprisingly harder with `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
 mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
 filter(x > 0) %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 slice(1L) %>% 
 pull(rn)

#[1]  1  4  7 11 12
```